# Xamarin.InAppBilling "Service Intent must be explicit"

Tags: android, xamarin, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have a working app made with Xamarin.Android, and I'm trying to add in-app purchases with the component [Xamarin.InAppBilling](http://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.inappbilling) v2.2

I use this code with my public key from the Google Play Developer Console.

```
_serviceConnection = new InAppBillingServiceConnection(activity, InAppBillingPublicKey);
_serviceConnection.OnConnected += LoadProducts;
_serviceConnection.Connect();
```

It fails with this exception message: "Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND }"

I can find others talking about this for plain android development, but not for Xamarin and this component. How do I make the component have the service intent set explicitly? Is there another way to to in-app-purchases in Xamarin.Android?

From other posts, I have found and tried this:

```
var intent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
intent.SetPackage("com.android.vending");
activity.BindService(intent, _serviceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
```

But it still won't work. I get the same error.

Comment: I am using the Microsoft Android Emulator, and I have installed the latest Google Play Services on it. I have the "<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />" in my manifest.

Comment: Have you able to solve it without changing the api level to 19 ?

Answer (score 0):

The error goes away i I set API level to 19 (was 21). But then I get another error from the linker. But for this case, it solves the problem.